# How can I upload Streaming media content to Azure?

Tags: c#, azure

I'm using dotnet core with c# and angular js UI in my project. I'm trying to upload streaming media content to Azure but everytime it is getting failed.
I've tried soo many approaches but none of them is working.
Please help me i'm stuck.

Comment: We need a bit more to go on here. Like what kind of data are you trying to stream? Which options have you tried and why/where did you fail? Please refer to [ask] and provide a [mcve].

Comment: Please provide more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This link might help you :

https://askgif.com/blog/314/uploading-streaming-media-content-to-azure/

I have been working at Swank Motion Pictures on a SmartTV application to offer a cloud-based on-demand streaming movie service. To do this, we upload our content to Azure Media Services assets and use OnDemand and SAS locators to stream the content on the TV. I have extracted a couple small methods into a simple class to help anyone looking to get started with uploading to Azure Media Services. While this example does not provide PlayReady DRM or other encryptions, this might be a helpful start.

```
/// <summary>
/// This class uploads files to Azure.
/// </summary>
public class SimpleAzureUploader
{
private readonly CloudMediaContext _context;

/// <summary>
/// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="SimpleAzureUploader"/> class.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="accountName">Name of the Azure Media Services account.</param>
/// <param name="accountKey">The Account key.</param>
public SimpleAzureUploader(string accountName, string accountKey)
{
    _context = new CloudMediaContext(accountName, accountKey);
}

/// <summary>
/// Uplodas a local folder to a non-encrypted asset in Azure.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="assetName">Name of the asset.</param>
/// <param name="path">The directory or file path.</param>
/// <param name="concurrentTransfers">The max number of concurrent transfers.</param>
/// <param name="parallelTransferThreads">The max number parallel transfer threads.</param>
/// <returns></returns>
public IAsset UploadAsset(string assetName, string path, int concurrentTransfers = 10, int parallelTransferThreads = 10)
{
    var blobTransferClient = new BlobTransferClient
    {
        NumberOfConcurrentTransfers = concurrentTransfers,
        ParallelTransferThreadCount = parallelTransferThreads
    };

    var asset = _context.Assets.Create(assetName, AssetCreationOptions.None);

    var uploadingAccessPolicy = _context.AccessPolicies.Create("Upload Policy", new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0, 0), AccessPermissions.Write | AccessPermissions.List);

    var uploadingLocator = _context.Locators.CreateLocator(LocatorType.Sas, asset, uploadingAccessPolicy);

    if (Directory.Exists(path) && new FileInfo(path).Attributes.HasFlag(FileAttributes.Directory))
    {
        UploadFolder(asset, uploadingLocator, path, blobTransferClient);
    }
    else
    {
        UploadFile(asset, uploadingLocator, path, blobTransferClient);
    }

    uploadingLocator.Delete();
    uploadingAccessPolicy.Delete();

    return asset;
}

/// <summary>
/// Uploads the folder to the existing asset.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="asset">The existing asset.</param>
/// <param name="locator">The uploading locator.</param>
/// <param name="folderPath">The folder path.</param>
/// <param name="blobTransferClient">The blob transfer client.</param>
/// <exception cref="System.IO.FileNotFoundException"></exception>
private void UploadFolder(IAsset asset, ILocator locator, string folderPath, BlobTransferClient blobTransferClient)
{
    var filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(folderPath);

    if (!filePaths.Any())
    {
        throw new FileNotFoundException(String.Format("No files in directory, check folderPath: {0}", folderPath));
    }

    Task.WaitAll((from filePath
                  in filePaths
                  let assetFile = asset.AssetFiles.Create(Path.GetFileName(filePath))
                  select assetFile.UploadAsync(filePath, blobTransferClient, locator, CancellationToken.None)).ToArray());
}

/// <summary>
/// Uploads the file to the existing asset.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="asset">The existing asset.</param>
/// <param name="locator">The uploading locator.</param>
/// <param name="filePath">The file path.</param>
/// <param name="blobTransferClient">The blob transfer client.</param>
private void UploadFile(IAsset asset, ILocator locator, string filePath, BlobTransferClient blobTransferClient)
{
    var assetFile = asset.AssetFiles.Create(Path.GetFileName(filePath));
    assetFile.UploadAsync(filePath, blobTransferClient, locator, CancellationToken.None).Wait();
}
}
```

Hope this will help.